# iOS 'dateFromString' Returning different?

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am using the NSDateFormatter's dateFromString, yet when it is given the string, it spits out different hours.

## code

```
NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateformatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
NSDate *firstDate = [dateformatter dateFromString:@"2017-06-02"];
NSDate *secondDate = [dateformatter dateFromString:@"2016-11-02"];
```

## output

```
firstDate:  2017-06-01 22:00:00 +0000
secondDate: 2016-11-01 23:00:00 +0000
```

I wonder why they do not have the same hour？

Comment: Whenever you print your date on Debugger then the printed Date will gets printed in UTC format, so the date which is printed on your debugger is conversion of your passed date into UTC if you want to further test it, then convert the same date into String and print it into the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify a time for the two dates, so they were initialized to midnight, local time. When you printed them they were displayed in UTC. Your local time zone (Central European Time) observed Daylight Savings Time from March 27, 2016 to October 30, 2016. Therefore the June midnight date, which fell under Daylight Savings, is 2 hours ahead of UTC (22:00:00), while the November midnight date, which did not fall under Daylight Savings, is only 1 hour ahead of UTC (23:00:00).